# Status, show elements in a presence probe

Tags: xmpp

What happens if I send a 'status', 'show' or 'priority' element set in a presence probe? How does an XMPP server handle this? I didn't see anything in the RFCs (3921[1], 6121[2]) about this particular case.

Is this implementation specific? Or should the server consider this as a genuine status/show update along with a presence probe to a contact and change the status/show of the user?

Did I miss reading some section in the RFCs?

Thanks!

[1] http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html

[2] http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of any other guidance, section [8.4 of RFC 6120](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-extended) says:

> If an intended recipient receives a message or presence stanza that
>   contains XML data qualified by a namespace it does not understand,
>   then it MUST ignore the portion of the stanza qualified by the unknown
>   namespace.

The receiving server, in all implementations that I know about, ignores everything inside the probe, where "ignore" is defined in [RFC 6120 section 1.4](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#intro-terms) as:

> discard the data without acting upon it or returning an error to the
>   sender